# Jquery closing div and ul tag and reopen new part II

Tags: jquery, html

More complex...
I have this html:

```
<div class="full">
   <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>Big Menu1   
       <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
         <li>menu3</li>
       </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Big Menu 2
         <ul>
            <li>menu1</li>  
            <li>menu2</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Big Menu 3
        <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
         <li>menu3</li>                       
       </ul>        
     </li> 
     <li>Big Menu 4</li>
     <li>Big Menu 5
        <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
         <li>menu3</li>                       
       </ul>        
     </li> 
     <li>Big Menu 6
       <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>   
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to change it for having 3 main "col" div, each ul inside will be incremeted.
Here is the code I would like to have:

```
<div class="full">
   <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>Big Menu1   
       <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
         <li>menu3</li>
       </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Big Menu 4</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <ul>
       <li>Big Menu 2
         <ul>
            <li>menu1</li>  
            <li>menu2</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Big Menu 5
          <ul>
            <li>menu1</li>
            <li>menu2</li>
            <li>menu3</li>                       
         </ul>        
       </li> 
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <ul>
       <li>Big Menu 3
        <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
         <li>menu3</li>                       
       </ul>        
     </li> 
     <li>Big Menu 6
       <ul>
         <li>menu1</li>
         <li>menu2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>   
    </ul>
  </div>                         
  </div>
```

Is it possible or too complex to be done with jQuery? I hope this is enough understanding.

Comment: This would be fairly easy to implement in jQuery. So just get to it :)

Comment: This is possible and not much complicated, although it looks rather like a task for server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

```
$m2 = $("li:contains('Big Menu 2')")
$m3 = $("li:contains('Big Menu 3')")
$m4 = $("li:contains('Big Menu 4')")
$m5 = $("li:contains('Big Menu 5')")
$m6 = $("li:contains('Big Menu 6')")
$(".full").append("<div class='col'><ul></ul></div>");
$("ul:last").append($m2).append($m5);
$(".full").append("<div class='col'><ul></ul></div>");
$("ul:last").append($m3).append($m6);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/amdro3f8/1/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

It helps me to create another jQuery code which could be dynamic according the number of "Big Menu" (1, 2, 6, etc.):
All li with Big Menu have a class name: lvl2

```
var proc1="";
var proc2="";   

$("li.lvl2").each(function()
{                   
    var liIndex = $(this).index();

    switch (liIndex)
    {           
        default:
            if (liIndex% 2 === 0 )
            {
                proc1=proc1+".append($('li.lvl2').eq("+liIndex+"))";                
            }
            else
            {
                proc2=proc2+".append($('li.lvl2').eq("+liIndex+"))";    
            }
        break;  
    }

});

$(".full").append("<div class='col'><ul></ul></div>");  
eval("$('ul:last')"+proc2);
$(".full").append("<div class='col'><ul></ul></div>");
eval("$('ul:last')"+proc1);
```

But I can't have what you got, I think I miss a little thing because the order is not the same. I can't find out.. :-/
Even when I make a switch with default values.